# How to separate pressing the UI button from pressing the screen in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

How to separate pressing the UI button from pressing the screen in Unity?

I have a button in the game (restart), but I also have a player who jumps when the screen is clicked. When restarting, it jumps because it reads the button press. Restart moves the player's position to the checkpoint position.

I tried disabling the move script, but I can't. Disabling the script is triggered only after pressing the button.

Answer (score 0):

You may need something to check if the clicked point overlaps with a UI element.
See:

```
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

...

if (!EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject())
{
    // Code here for operations when the clicked point is not UI element
    // such as buttons. 
    // for example, do your jump logic here
}
```

You can also check the documentation of Unity for IsPointerOverGameObject() method: https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.EventSystem.IsPointerOverGameObject.html